# Determinant of block matrix with left and right eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, orthogonality, block-matrices

Can we, without further information, find the determinant
$$
    \det\begin{pmatrix}
        A & \vec{b} \\
        \vec{c}^T & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A\in\mathbb{C}^{N \times N}; \ \vec{b}, \vec{c} \in\mathbb{C}^N$ and we know that

- $A$ is invertible,
- $\vec{b}, \vec{c}^T$ are right and left eigenvectors respectively with the same non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$. ($\vec{b}^TA=\lambda\vec{b}^T$, $A\vec{c}=\lambda\vec{c}$),
- $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are orthogonal ($\vec{c}^T\vec{b}=0$).

I used the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) to get
$$
    \det\begin{pmatrix}
        A & \vec{b} \\
        \vec{c}^T & 0
    \end{pmatrix} = 0\det(A) - \vec{c}^T\text{adj}(A)\vec{b} = -\det(A) \ \vec{c}^T A^{-1}\vec{b}.
$$
But it feels like there should be some nice result, like that it is $0$ always.

Comment: @Surb but $\vec{b}$ is a **left** eigenvector of $A$, therefore we only would have $A^T\vec{b}=\lambda\vec{b}$ (pay attention to the transpose ^T).

Comment: right, my bad, overlooked that.